# В списке вопросов отображены изменения по удалённым сообщениям, даже если их нельзя посмотреть в силу недостаточной репутации

Tags: дефект, предложение, даты, список-вопросов

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта дата изменения показана даже пользователям, которые не могут видеть удалённые сообщения.

По-хорошему, нужно отображать дату только тех изменений, которые могут быть просмотрены пользователем.

Comment: Спорный вопрос, действительно ли пользователю плохо знать о факте изменения если сами изменения он не может просмотреть? Если да, то насколько это критичная вещь чтобы писать дополнительную логику?

Comment: @yolosora меня б смутило. И да, я думаю, большинство пользователей не в курсе привилегии на просмотр удалённых сообщений.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, дата и дата, что-то недоступное всё равно с этого не выцепить, а так может даже будет подогревать интерес узнать, а что же там такое. Отдельно брать даты разных действий, чтобы отобразить их в списке для разнореповых участников? Если отображать дату не последнего события, приведшего к поднятию вопроса, то могут появиться довольно странные ситуации в списках, отсортированных вроде как по дате обновления:

- изменён 1 час назад   // последнее изменение затрагивает удалённое сообщение
- изменён 20 минут назад // все сообщения видны
- изменён 5 минут назад // снова затрагивает удалённое сообщение

Здесь я ещё хотел бы заметить более интересные ситуации, когда в списке есть указание обновления недавнего, а в самом вопросе, когда заходишь дата не отражает изменений недавних. Но оказывается кто-то начал конкурс, например. Или Дух просто поднял сообщение из-за отсутствия голосов на ответах.

Comment: Там Glorfindel неплохое предложение сделал https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323821/260198